# Batch taskkill won't kill

Tags: batch-file, automation

Ok so I'm trying to end Comodo (free firewall service) so that I can install NVidia driver updates, and since I'm super lazy I want this all to be automatic whenever NVidia tries to update. After I want to reopen Comodo.
However I'm stuck on the first step since I have no idea on how to properly end Comodo, when I try taskkill it says:

ERROR: The process "cis.exe" with PID 6204 could not be terminated.
Reason: Element not found.

I'm new to batch and have no idea what this error message means since I can clearly see that "cis.exe" (which is Comodo) is running in the background at least and I can close it from the icon tray if I wanted to, and it spits out the same message when I try using "CisTray.exe".

Also any advice on where I should go for the next few parts would be greatly appreciated, thinking on using task scheduler to open the batch file when some kind of log or something is made by NVidia.

Comment: Did you try `/f` with `taskkill` ? Have you tried to stop it like you normally stop services ?

Comment: both /f and /t don't work, and if by stop it like normal you mean just close it like normal or with taskmanager, then that's not the issue. I can close it normally, i just want to close it using some kind of automation.

Comment: I think Marged means do you try using `net stop Cis` or whatever the service name is. You can use `services.msc`  (run from CMD prompt) to see if it is a service and what the service name is.

Comment: alright so running `services.msc` I got that the service is probably CmdAgent (Display name says COMODO Internet Security Helper Service, so I'm pretty sure I would just need to end that) but when I run `net stop CmdAgent` it spits out hlpmessage 2191, which says `The requested pause, continue, or stop is not valid for this service.` So what now?

Comment: Just gonna add this here, Comodo is very resilient to anything but itself killing it, there are options in the GUI to add exclusions to let other things kill it (if you want) but the NVidia/Comodo thing is a bug that is documented and they are working on a patch (not sure if they finished it?) anyway if someone wants to do something similar to what I was trying to do, you could either go lower and lower in languages (assembly comes to mind) or just go sideways and see if whatever your trying to kill has an easy way of killing itself.